# Image is not exists in CodeIgniter return 200 Ok

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, redis

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and issue is on a specific path,

if image does not exist, it should return 404 not found
but it is returning 200 Ok

checked hook, helper, and controller but didn't understand.

Getting

Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image is not exists in CodeIgniter return 200 Ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146340/image-is-not-exists-in-codeigniter-return-200-ok)

Comment: @OlafKock: Nope, That was same question asked by me. May be clicked submit button twice so published twice

Comment: You definitely need to share some code. Otherwise even an educated guess is not possible